# How did Joey not know Ross was the father immediately, if Ross was with Joey before he slept with Rachel

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

Joey and Ross are together discussing the Europe story. Joey has Ross record himself to practice, and then Rachel comes in which is how they end up being videotaped, thus he’s already wearing the red sweater. If Joey realizes the red sweater was the father’s, and Ross was wearing the sweater, shouldn’t he have known Ross was the father? I don’t think they can pawn this off on Joey being dumb.

Comment: I think you've underestimated what can or can't be pawned off on Joey being dumb.  Remember, this is a grown man who somehow [doesn't understand sarcastic air quotes.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bW8OkSJvhvE)

Comment: It's Joey. if it's not either Food or Pretty girl, nothing stays and bother him in his mind.. Simplish slow-witted guy who usually gets last glimpse on sarcasm(consider him being best friend of Chandler and still getting his sarcastic comments last)

Answer (score 8):

I think:

1. Joey is aware of the history of Ross and Rachel, so (for Joey) the chances that the sweater is Ross', and thus Ross being the father, are slim to none. So that idea might have subconsciously flew over his head.
2. As far as we (audiences) are concerned, the episode with the red sweater was aired before the one with the videotape, so at that point, we didn't know and that's important.
3. You can blame it on Joey being slow-witted. I mean it's Joey. He has done worse than that. Also, the thing happened a month before the events of the red sweater, so it's `Joey x 30`.

Comment: “He has done worse than that.” He, for example, forgot that his apartment used to have carpets before Monica took them up and buffed the floorboards.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yeah! That's Joey.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing scene when Rachel told Ross about pregnancy. The one dubbed "Condoms only work like 97% of the time".
Joey reaction to the news from Ross show that he didn't suspected Ross to be father because he EXPECTED Ross to use condoms. And that Rachel/Ross child was effect of their secret agreement rather then accident.